# ORA-04061 existing state of has been of type body has been invalidated

Tags: oracle, plsql

In oracle APEX after recompile of my type i get error:
ORA-04061 existing state of has been of type body has been invalidated. Even if i call dbms_session.reset_package() before constucting my type(object), i still get this.
This is runtime error, in database everything works fine, and types are compiled with no problem.

Anyone know's what cause type body to become invalid?

Comment: We'd need to see the code, but when it occurs, check LAST_DDL_TIME in ALL_OBJECTS to see what else had some DDL around that timeframe. That might assist in locating what DDL is causing the type to need recompilation and hence lose its state